# Android setVisibility(View.GONE) and setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) not work as expected

Tags: android

In the following code when select Search By Name option click, ID EditText box view. When Search by ID click, Name EditText box view. Following is the layout XML file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testingserver.SearchMember" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:text="Search" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="ID"
        android:visibility="gone"
         />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Name"
        android:visibility="gone"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity class function is as follows.

```
package com.example.testingserver;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SearchMember extends Activity  implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    Integer[] option_values= {0,1, 2, 3};
    EditText editTextID;
    EditText editTextName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_member);

        editTextID= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
        editTextName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

        String[] options= {"Select","Search By ID", "Search By Name", "Search By Phone"};
        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);  
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);  

      //Creating the ArrayAdapter instance having the country list  
        ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, options);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner  
        spin.setAdapter(aa);  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_member, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //EditText editTextID= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
        //EditText editTextName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        int opt= position;



        switch(opt){
        case 1:
            editTextID.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editTextName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;

        case 2:
            editTextName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editTextID.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;

            default:
        }
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), websites[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

When select Search By ID option variable opt is 1 but name edit text box become visible. When Search by Name option select, variable opt is bcome 2 and ID edit box is visible. Seems switch statement is working properly.But result is not what I expected.

Comment: why you are not find your view at `onCreate`?

Comment: Although find view at `onCreate`, It wouldn't work. Same result occur.

Comment: please give whole activity code

Comment: @VimalGajera I added full activity code. Please see that.

Comment: In this code, select id -->id text field is visible and on select name -->name text field visible. now what you expected?

Comment: @VimalGajera Yes Gajera.

Comment: @GayanFernando please say what is your expectation?

Comment: do you only two `case` for you spinner?

Comment: When Search By Id option select, It should display ID textbox. But appear Name text box.

Comment: @Mohit It is not clear for me what you asked Mohit.

Comment: i have tried your code every thing is fine ..except you need to call `findViewById` at `onCreate`

Comment: @GayanFernando This code work perfectly,means i select ID its appear ID text field

Comment: @Mohit I added findeViewById at `onCreate`. But it still same result. Why I dont get correct result?:((

Comment: try clean and rebuilt your project

Answer (score -1):

please check may be you find id with one another name means edittextname with id and edittextid with name on oncreate.